# Purchases.products: get Api

Tags: java

I’m trying to get product information but something is going wrong. Does anybody have an idea of what actually is going wrong?

```
String query ="https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/jksldf/purchases/products/kmdsd/tokens/kjls"

  HttpURLConnection connection;
            try {
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(query).openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.setUseCaches(false);
                connection.connect();
                if (HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK == connection.getResponseCode()) {
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                    String line;
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(line);
                        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(stringBuilder);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                throwable.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the error you get when sending this request (at least if you get an error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I paste the url in my browser I also get an error stating:

```
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
```

this means that you will need an acces token to be able to consume their API

Comment: how i can get that token?

Comment: but in the google api example there is no acces token

Comment: it is in case of subscriptions